# Model field not updating in admin page even if value changes

Tags: python, django

I apologize for my confusing title but I hope the code explains it better.
In my `views.py` file I have the follow view

```
def create_view(request):
     context = {}

     form = CreateForm(request.POST)

     if request.method == "POST":
         if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()
            instance.author.profile.participating_in = Post.objects.get(
                title=instance.title
            )
            instance.save()
            print(instance.author.profile.participating_in)

     context["form"] = form
     return render(request, "post/post_form.html", context)
```

when I print out the value of `instance.author.profile.participating_in` it shows up in my terminal however when I check the admin page it doesnt update at all. I'm sure I messed up somewhere silly but I cant seem to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`participating_in` is the `profile` model field, but you are not calling the `save()` method for profile anywhere.

You have to do it like the following:

```
profile = instance.author.profile
profile.participating_in = Post.objects.get(title=instance.title)
profile.save()
```

If `participating_in` is `ManyToManyField` then we can do it like this:

```
post = Post.objects.get(title=instance.title)
instance.author.profile.participating_in.add(post)
```

> Note that `add()`, `create()`, `remove()`, `clear()`, and `set()` all
> apply database changes immediately for all types of related fields. In
> other words, there is no need to call save() on either end of the
> relationship.

Look at [Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)

Comment: this was such a big help! thanks so much. Can't believe I missed something so obvious

Comment: @AlanWeng, happy to help.  It can always happen, that's nothing. Keep going and be happy))))